# Java- How to write a lobby game server

Tags: java

So I'm writing a Chess matchmaking system based on a Lobby view with gaming rooms, general chat etc. So far I have a working prototype  but I have big doubts regarding some things I did with the server. Writing a gaming lobby server is a new programming experience to me and so I don't have a clear nor precise programming model for it. I also couldn't find a paper that describes how it should work. I ordered "Java Network Programming 3rd edition" from Amazon and still waiting for shipment, hopefully I'll find some useful examples/information in this book.

Meanwhile, I'd like to gather your opinions and see how you would handle some things so I can learn how to write a server correctly. Here are a few questions off the top of my head: (may be more will come)

First, let's define what a server does. It's primary functionality is to hold TCP connections with clients, listen to the events they generate and dispatch them to the other players. But is there more to it than that?

Should I use one thread per client? If so, 300 clients = 300 threads. Isn't that too much? What hardware is needed to support that? And how much bandwidth does a lobby consume then approx?

What kind of data structure should be used to hold the clients' sockets? How do you protect it from concurrent modification (eg. a player enters or exists the lobby) when iterating through it to dispatch an event without hurting throughput? Is ConcurrentHashMap the correct answer here, or are there some techniques I should know?

When a user enters the lobby, what mechanism would you use to transfer the state of the lobby to him? And while this is happening, where do the other events bubble up?

Input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Screenshot : http://goo.gl/pYqM3

Answer (score -1):

The first thing to note is that **there is no single right answer**. There are a million different and perfectly valid ways to roll up something like this.

It's good that you're thinking about various aspects of your design up front, but beware that trying to decide too many things about your design up front will slow you down and lead to probably not the best design. The reason is that no longer how long and hard you think at the beginning, **you don't know what problems you're going to hit until you hit them**.

If you're doing this from scratch, I strongly recommend applying [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), which takes this approach to designing software:

1. Pick a small feature to implement next
2. Write a **failing** test case that will pass only when the feature is correctly implemented
3. Write the minimum amount of code possible to make the test pass
4. Go to step 1

Forcing all new code to be exercised right away makes sure you encounter problems as soon as possible. You also end up with a suite of automated tests that ensures you have a working system at any point.

After applying this for a few cycles you'll already see the design starting to emerge. Doing it in short cycles also gives you a chance to frequently evaluate what's the next most important feature, instead of rabbit-trailing into the details of a not-so-important feature for days.

There's a great deal of literature out there about TDD. I recommend checking some of these out:

- [I Pity The Fool Who Doesn't Write Unit Tests](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/i-pity-the-fool-who-doesnt-write-unit-tests.html)
- [Writing Great Unit Tests: Best and Worst Practices](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/08/24/writing-great-unit-tests-best-and-worst-practises/)
- [JUnit Test Infected: Programmers Love Writing Tests](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/testinfected/testing.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm not asking questions too soon; I already have a working prototype. As far as tests go, if only I could do them. The problem is that I need actual concurrent connections and users doing various things. How can I do that..?